# Get rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

What kind of query would I need to write if I need to get the rows from the `products`, and `subcontent` tables, which the `image_id` field matches `$id`?

**Images Table**

```
mysql> show columns from images;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select * from images;
+----+-------------+
| id | file_name   |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | image_1.png |
|  2 | image_2.png |
|  3 | image_3.png |
|  4 | image_4.png |
+----+-------------+
```

**Products Table**

```
mysql> show columns from products;
+----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | text                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image_id | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select * from products;
+----+-----------------+----------+
| id | title           | image_id |
+----+-----------------+----------+
|  1 | Product Title 1 | 2        |
|  2 | Product Title 2 | 1        |
+----+-----------------+----------+
```

**SubContent Table**

```
mysql> show columns from subcontent;
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(255)           | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| image_id | mediumint(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select * from subcontent;
+----+--------------------+----------+
| id | title              | image_id |
+----+--------------------+----------+
|  1 | SubContent Title 1 | 2        |
|  2 | SubContent Title 2 | 3        |
+----+--------------------+----------+
```

**Result I am looking for if `$id=2`**

```
+---------------------+
| title               |
+---------------------+
| Product Title 1     |
| SubContent Title 1  |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) syntax:

```
SELECT title FROM products WHERE image_id = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT title FROM subcontent WHERE image_id = 2
```

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple `SELECT` statements into a single result set.

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation? This popped up in the review queue.

Comment: Hard to add an explanation to something as trivial as this? It's a chapter 1 query, in a chapter 1 answer. But good to see @BrianGlick gets upvoted for copying my answer with less readability and adding a pointless 6 words to it.

Comment: If it was so basic that it doesn't warrant explanation, the question wouldn't have been asked. I didn't upvote anyone... but, a code-only answer with no explanation tends to get upvoted less. I'll add one and upvote it as an example of what a good explanation might be for even a simple question/answer. No disrespect whatsoever, just trying to help :)

Comment: I think your first statement is quite naive - in my experience 80% of the SO questions boil down to 'RTFM' with that being more than enough explanation   ;)   I don't mind, it's what SO is about mostly - bad programmers faking competence through other people. This question is a marvelous example of someone trying to program without bothering to read up on the first basics of SQL programming. I'll help just fine when I'm bored but it's not my position to copy/paste a SQL tutorial here every day. If TS cares he can Google 'sql union' himself just fine. Most people on SO don't.

Comment: Some people learn better by example. To me, it's not about the user who asked the question, as much as it's about helping ALL of the people who have the question now or later. We're creating a giant living document of programming resources, that, yes, can enable people without competence to program. But that competence can be built with time. Some people can read all of the manuals in the world, but don't get it, until they can tie it to a real-world example. Some people don't know what to google. Now, someone who googles "get rows from multiple tables" can find a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a UNION ALL

`(SELECT title FROM products WHERE image_id = $id) UNION ALL (SELECT title FROM subcontent WHERE image_id = $id)`